# How to change with jQuery a data attribute of a set of elements?

Tags: jquery

say I have a set of elements $elements. Say they all have a data attr named "amount". First one has data-amount = 1, second 2 and so on. Whats the simplest way to increment in x that value for all of them. y solution is

```
$elements.each(function(){
    $(this).data('amount',$(this).data('amount')+=x);
});
```

Is there a better solution, without using the each statement?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery, as of v1.6.2 at least, doesn't offer an overload for `.data()` that accepts a function. Still using `each`, but within it you can do:

```
$(this).data().amount += x;
```

Comment: @Šime Vidas, yes because `.data()` without parameters returns the raw object jQuery uses to store the data. In fact, it's recommended in the jQuery documentation for getting/setting multiple properties.

Comment: Great feature. And it's been around since 1.4 - it was about time that I find out about it `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$elements.data('amount', function () {
    return $(this).data('amount') += x;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!isn't that the same? Anyway you are still using "each". Isn't there another way?

Comment: I would do `$.data(this, 'amount') += x;`...to save on creating the otherwise unused object...all you really want is something like `this[$.expando].amount += x` anyway.  You could of course do this raw in a fast loop like that too, just depends how much performance matters here.

Comment: Perhaps Tomalak updated his answer, but I sure don't see any `each` involved.

Comment: I don't believe that use exists for `.data()`, unlike `.text()` for example. You probably also meant `+ x` instead of `+= x` ;-)

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the hint about performance. I'll change the answer to the way I had in mind from the start, so your comment remains in context (and valid).